How can I override the default startup command for an Azure Container App using Azure Cli?
I would override the startup command to my Mosquitto image on the Azure Container App to start with an anonymous user config. It is a simple bash command that can run as shown below. When I use this command directly in the creation dialog of the Container App in the Azure portal, it works fine. But the instance crashes When I use it in my Azure Cli (If I don't use the command parameter in Azure CLI, it works fine. So the problem is about the command. I have no additional details regarding the error message in the portal or Cli). I use this command in Powershell. Please let me know how I can fix this problem:
Command to start the Mosquitto:
/bin/sh, -c, /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c mosquitto-no-auth.conf

Azure CLI command:
az containerapp create `
  --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
  --name "my-message-broker" `
  --image 'eclipse-mosquitto:latest' `
  --environment $myEnv `
  --ingress external `
  --target-port 1883 `
  --exposed-port 1883 `
  --allow-insecure false `
  --workload-profile-name Consumption `
  --transport tcp `
  --command '/bin/bash, -c, /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c mosquitto-no-auth.conf'

What I have tried so far:
--command '/bin/bash' '-c'  '/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c mosquitto-no-auth.conf'

--command '/bin/bash -c /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c mosquitto-no-auth.conf'

--command '/bin/bash'
--args  '-c'  '/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c mosquitto-no-auth.conf'

--command '/bin/bash -c'
--args  '/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c mosquitto-no-auth.conf'

--command '/bin/bash'
--args  '-c /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c mosquitto-no-auth.conf'


--args '-c', '/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c mosquitto-no-auth.conf' when you do this in azure cli it's crashing?

@Arko In this case I get error from the CLI: unrecognized arguments: -c /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c mosquitto-no-auth.conf

You get something like this
Failed (View details ) 1/1 Failed:my-message-brokerContainerCrashing is it?

@SiamakFerdos Try using --command '["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /mosquitto/config/mosquitto-no-auth.conf"]'

@SiamakFerdos Have you created Dockerfile using eclipse-mosqitto image and added .conf inside container in path /usr/sbin/mosquitto

I tried the command --command '/bin/bash' --args '-c /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /mosquitto/config/mosquitto-no-auth.conf', and it's working fine for me. The container app deployed successfully.


How can I override the default startup command for an Azure Container App using Azure Cli?

If you are using the CLI to create a Container App and need to specify a command to override the default startup command, you must specify the command properly.
I created a container app with bash commands by separating the –command and –args parameters using the command below.

Note: Make sure the mosquitto-no-auth.conf file is accessible within the container.

Applications with external TCP ingress can only be deployed to Container App Environments that have a custom VNET. Set ingress traffic to Limited to Container Apps Environment if you want to deploy to a Container App Environment without a custom VNET.
    az containerapp create `
      --resource-group "RG_Name" `
      --name "my-message-broker" `
      --image 'eclipse-mosquitto:latest' `
      --environment managedEnvironment-Venkat-ad01 `
      --ingress internal `
      --target-port 1883 `
      --exposed-port 1883 `
      --allow-insecure false `
      --workload-profile-name Consumption `
      --transport tcp `
      --command '/bin/bash'`
      --args  '-c /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /mosquitto/config/mosquitto-no-auth.conf'


Output:


